# gdax restful api

Tags: coinbase.com

Gdax has a restful api. It has developed a node.js api for it which I have worked with and works well. However I don't intend to develop a server. I would like to write a similar api for client side.

Can anyone point me in a direction to do this? I suspect I can use socket.io to do this, but don't really know? I will need to alter the http headers on get requests and what not as well as send json in body I think. Can any one provide information on this, perhaps on existing client api's, or information about restful requests, socket.io, or easy way to cover more to client js.

I know this is kind of open ended, vaguely related to bitcoin in it's core problem, and vague. I have asked similar on stack exchange but said is off topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need socket.io. You just need to make HTTP requests for the REST API, and use a websocket client to connect to their websocket server (if indeed you need to use the websocket API).

Everything should be very close to what you see in the GDAX node.js API client (not an API, btw, but a client of GDAX's API). The only difference is that you use browser based implementations for HTTP and Websocket requests/connections (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not experienced with js. I feel ther should be a c library, I would even write one but then id have to do openssl which is a pain. But I figured it out. For rest i use httpgetrequest( url, ...) and for websocket I use the new websocket.

Comment: Not sure what crypto library to use for authenticated request were I have to sha sign the api keys.